# Why does a slip line form in between these 2 shocks?

Tags: shock-waves

[image]

As seen here, the trailing edge shock creates what looks like a slip line between the two shocks. I thought a slip line only formed when air that went through different shock systems interacted, so what am I missing?

Why does this slip line form in this case?

Comment: I think this is just be the boundary layer leaving the trailing edge

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either this wing is at a slight angle of attack -- resulting in different accelerations across the uppper and lower surface -- resulting in different Mach number before the shock and therefore different shocks -- and therefore a slip line.

Or, the shocks are identical and what you are seeing is not a slip line, but instead the trace of the boundary layer.

I am not positive the technique used to generate this image.  It may be a Schlieren photograph, shadowgraph, or inteferogram.  Each of these will render different flow features slightly differently, but they're fundamentally based on visualizing gradients in density.

Comment: Ah okay that makes sense. In this case, do you think the boundary layer is higher density, so it shows up on this picture? I thought the boundary layer was the same pressure/density as the surrounding air, but just more turbulent in some cases.

Comment: Pressure is constant across a boundary layer, but temperature can vary.  P=rho R T.  These techniques image density gradient -- so changes in density, either increasing or decreasing.

Comment: Ah okay, thanks! I imagine the temperature is slightly higher in the BL, as it's experiencing the most friction. Also, can you model the pressure in the BL as $P=pRT$?

Comment: P=rho R T works as long as a gas behaves like a gas.  When a gas starts acting like a plasma (extreme high temperatures and low pressures) or like a liquid (extreme high pressures and low temperatures) this can break down.  You have to be careful in chemically reacting flow because the value of R can change -- but P=rho R T still works.

Comment: I see. So is $P=pRT$ the same as P=rho R T? (I'm not too familiar with P = rho R T)

Comment: rho is the spelling of the greek letter $\rho$, which is the symbol for density.  The symbol you are using looks to me like a lower case  p rather than a $\rho$.

Comment: Ah okay, thanks for the clarification!